# relative path always pointing to root

Tags: html

I am trying to install a symphony project web on a differenct server. All is set except that on that server all the relative paths ("./images/test_image.png") are returning to root (/) instead of current folder location (/app/) I have removed the .htaccess in case it was causing that but I have the same problem.
For example when I over this href

```
<a ui-sref="user.wishlist" href="#/users/wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Wishlist</a>
```

The location say `myserverHostname.com/#/users/wishlist` instead of  `myserverHostname.com/app/#/users/wishlist`

Same thing is happending with img tags and css they looks all broken.

Comment: If you want to reference an anchor say #anchorname, to traverse a path say /path/to/foo. You cannot possibly combine them.  So, if I understand correctly,  your link would look like /app/users/wishlist

Comment: actually the current link path is /app/ and img tag for example have its source set to "images/49.png" on the chrome console it say that it cannot find mydomain.com/images/49.png .... of course it can´t because images is located inside app not in the root

Comment: There's no img reference in the link you posted above. However, if neither images/49.png nor ./images/49.png (mind the leading dot) nor /app/images/49.png work, you have a broken configuration somewhere. Not sure how the hash fits in, though. Check your console's path settings.

Comment: nevermind the hash... the has is working if you click it but it you right click and open the link on a new page it is loading the root url instead of the actual one. 
img is working with  /app/images/49.png but I need it working with the relative path instead. I am almost sure that when the img relative path issue is fixed the a anchor tag will work as well on a new tab

Comment: Just ran this on localhost. Works OK without the hash but fails if I leave the hash in the link. Well, good luck then.

Comment: Maybe the issue caused by tag `<base href="http://myserverHostname.com/">` in the head of page?

Comment: thanks !! please post it as an aswer to accept it.